# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: -1 < 0 in SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: java, android, spannablestring

I have an `EditText` with Clickable `Spannable` String.

But if the content contains a `Spannable` String and I tap on it or move the cursor 
in it, I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**Here is my error log.**

````
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: -1 < 0
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.charAt(SpannableStringBuilder.java:112)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:81)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:115)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.updateSelection(Editor.java:3697)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.positionAtCursorOffset(Editor.java:3417)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.updatePosition(Editor.java:3444)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.widget.Editor$PositionListener.onPreDraw(Editor.java:2285)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:707)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1936)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1105)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4462)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
05-22 12:28:01.413: E/AndroidRuntime(5482):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)```
````

Comment: Please add the code associated with the error.

Comment: "_anyone can Know hoe to solve it_" Don't try to access an index which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Index values start from `0`. You are trying to access the character at index `-1` (Which is an Illegal index) That's why you get the exception. May be you have to fix the loop which gets out of the valid index, while traversing the characters.

Please check out [IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) API

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, looked like it was caused by **LinkMovementMethod**, used for my EditText with ClickableSpan.

In my case issue reproduced only with `editText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`

So, to handle clicks on ClickableSpan without LinkMovementMethod - add custom onClickListener, something like this:

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Editable editable = editText.getText();
                int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();
                ClickableSpan[] link = editable.getSpans(pos,pos, ClickableSpan.class);
                if (link.length != 0) {
                    link[0].onClick(v);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Nice answer, should the above have a "int posend = editText.getSelectionEnd();" and then a revised "ClickabkeSpan[] link = editable.getSpants(pos, posend, ClickableSpan.class)'"?